# Disable browser auto-complete/auto-fill for username and password form fields?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a custom username and password field in my form which is independent from the normal website login.

```
public function getFormFieldUsername() {
  return [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Username *',
      '#attributes' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'],
    ];
  }

  public function getFormFieldPassword() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#title' => 'Password *',
      '#attributes' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'],
    ];
  }
```

The `'#attributes' => ['autocomplete' => 'off'],` doesn't block the auto-fill from the browser tho. Is there a way to achieve that anyways?

Comment: Did you check that the input field has the `autocomplete` attribute set to `off` , in the browser ?

Comment: If the attribute is in the HTML, and the browser's still filling it in, you'll need to take it up with the browser's developers, or [hack around it](https://www.20spokes.com/blog/what-to-do-when-chrome-ignores-autocomplete-off-on-your-form). Drupal's only job in this is getting the HTML rendered, after that it can't do anything to control how the browser interprets it

Comment: Aaah, so Chrome is the culprit. I'll have a look at the link to hack around it. :)